# How to connect a device (which is outside the greengrass group) to a greengrass group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

How can one connect the java application running outside the greengrass group to a greengrass group ? Kindly help me with this. Any thoughts/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your java program could be acting as a [Greengrass Aware Device (GGAD)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/device-group.html) and connecting to Greengrass Core (GGC) using MQTT protocol. However, your java program will need to have a device certificate and be part of the group. 
An alternative is that you have a user lambda running inside your GGC and it opens a port for the external java program to connect to.  The user lambda can be , for example, an HTTP server.